# Is the algebraic closure of the rational functions over R a subset of the set of partial functions from R to C?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $R(x)$ denote the rational functions over the reals and $\overline{R(x)}$ its algebraic closure. Also let $P(X,Y)$ denote the set of partial functions from $X$ to $Y$, where partial functions means in simple terms a "function" for which not every term in the domain is mapped.

Lastly let $h$ be the canonical homomorphism $h:R(x)\rightarrow P(R,R)$ that is described by simply evaluating the rational function over the $R$.

My question is whether there exists a homomorphism $f:\overline{R(x)}\rightarrow P(R,C)$ such that $f|_{R(x)}=h$ and $f(\sqrt[n]{q})=\sqrt[n]{f(q)}$

It is clear or any element of $\overline{R(x)}$ that can be expressed through the field operations of the rational functions and roots we have an obvious corresponding partial function associated with it (simply evaluate the expression as you would in an grade school algebra class). However, there are many elements of $\overline{R(x)}$ that are not expressible through roots and arithmetic operations and so this questions boils down to is there meaningful and consistent way of "evaluating" them over the reals so that the outputs lie entirely within $C$ whilst agreeing the the above mentioned canonical mapping of rational functions.

A pure existence proof for this correspondence would be nice but a construction for a method of evaluation for any $q\in \overline{R(x)}$

Comment: What do you mean by "the set of functions over C"? 

Comment: I am not sure if that's what you are asking but, no, $\sqrt x$ is not in $\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Comment: Thinking of subsets alone may probably be the wrong intuition here. Try to consider maps between the rings of such functions, and see what goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I have made what I meant much more precise now. This kinda of problem seems like that kind that has a clear answer and a method of construction as well.

Comment: how is $P(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$ made into a ring? what is the domain of $F\cdot G$ if $F$ and $G$ are partial functions? Assuming you come up with an answer, apply it to $F=G=\sqrt{x}$. Whatever the domain of this $F$ is, I doubt that the domain of $F^2$ will be the domain of $x$ (the identity), so $h$ will hardly be a homomorphism.

Comment: PS i think this is a great thought-provoking question though.

Comment: PPS i meant the *extension* of $h$ will hardly be a homomorphism, should it exist.

Comment: There's not much point in editing a question once it has been closed, since no one can post an answer, unless you also open a thread on meta asking people to look at the new wording and consider reopening (in which case you post a link here to the discussion on meta). Alternatively, one can just post a new question (with a link to the old one). 

Comment: Thanks Pierre for pointing out that big hole about $P(R,C)$ not having a clear ring structure. I will think about that and see if that can be resolved in a nice way. As for your comment about $\sqrt{x}$, I would say there is no problem since I would define the domain to be $R$ and the codomain to be $C$ so that $\sqrt{−a}=\sqrt{a}i$ for $a>0$.